# Would the time dilation from being in low orbit around a black hole delay/slow the effects of quantum tunneling?

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics

If quantum tunneling will cause rigid objects like rocks to rearrange their atoms into a slow-moving liquid-like state in ~10^65 years, could an object delay this fate through time dilation in a low, stable orbit around a black hole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10^65 years aren't enough for you?*

Yes, for time as experienced by an observer distant from the black hole. An object always experiences its own proper time, however. For another exercise in time dilation, see [The Twin Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_paradox).

*When you start talking about ridiculously long periods of time like that, you have to take into account a lot of things we normally would neglect. Your black hole might emit non-negligible Hawking radiation in that time, protons might be unstable, etc.

Comment: on a much shorter time, the gravitational wave losses would cause the rock to spiral into the black hole.

Comment: Precisely... you have to take *everything* into account when you extrapolate that far out, because even processes that normally get totally blown off and ignored can become dominant after long enough times.